# confusion in async flow using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

```py
import asyncio
import json

def save_settings(event, context):

    async def background_processing():
        import time
        time.sleep(2)
        print("123")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(1)


    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  
    loop.run_until_complete(background_processing())  
    loop.close() 

    # Return the response immediately
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({
            'message': 'Background process initiated successfully'
        })
    }
    return response
```

actually I want to run this function in background and return success response immediately . Only this code should run in background:

```py
async def background_processing():
    import time
    time.sleep(2)
    print("123")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(1)
```

but on running all code is running in sequence and not getting json return

Comment: It does return your json response and it runs sequentially as to your not-async design.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest how I can achieve my desire result then ?

Comment: You are calling the async function instead of passing it.

Change the line to

    `loop.run_until_complete(background_processing)`. If this still does not work, you have issues in your design.

Comment: Design in sense ?  I am trying to just run this chunk of code in online compiler  https://onecompiler.com/python/3zdqt8wtq   this is whole design @Sebastian